# Keyboard column not responding

Tags: keyboard

Have a keyboard with hotswap sockets that was previously working... suddenly one column no longer works. Specifically the column consisting of 6yhn does not work anymore.

Here is a link to the schematic https://nicekeyboards.com/docs/nice-60/schematic

Pics of the keys:

6:[image: 6]

y:[image: y]

h:[image: h]

n:[image: n]

And these are things I've tried:

1. Diode tests on all the non-working keys. All passed.
2. Continuity tests[image: continuity tests] between the two ends of the sockets of non-working keys. All passed.
3. Continuity tests between the end of the socket and the top of the diode (yellow line in image). All passed
4. Continuity test between the end of the socket and the bottom of the diode (blue line in the image. All failed (including known working keys).
5. Inspected solder pads for lifting. None.
6. Inspected column traces[image: column traces] for damage. None.
7. Inspected the MCU[image: MCU] for issues (it's under the Bluetooth chip), and I don't think there's anything.
8. Switched the GPIO for the column in firmware, and connected the GPIO pin to one of the column socket pads. Same behavior as the default GPIO.

I'm actually at a loss at what else to test. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the old GPIO pulling the voltage down for the column. After changing GPIOs, I had to cut the trace for the old GPIO.

Comment: what's an `old GPIO`?

Comment: The default GPIO that the column came hard-wired to in the PCB.

Comment: Could I receive clarification on what exactly you did to resolve your issue? I am also having the exact same issue you are (6yhn column not working on the nice!60) but am at a loss for what you did. You mention an old GPIO that someone else asked about earlier, but I don't know what you're referring to as the default GPIO and "old" GPIO. I have checked everything as you did, and found no issues either other than the voltage measuring .43V across the column 7 sockets instead of the ~2.9V across working sockets.

Comment: Soper was able to find my discussion with the maker of the board over at the official Discord (https://discord.gg/CHd6hUy)

Comment: But I'll summarize what I needed to do for posterity:


1) disconnecting that column from the existing GPIO (3.0 I think) with an Xacto knife - (https://discord.com/channels/675924128108118016/713979311228715049/865057109406515200)
 

2) Change the keymap to use new GPIO (I chose 21) - https://github.com/hahuang65/zmk-config/commit/094310bed5602a1fe93a60a3e79e7c14f07d7c56


3) Connect the right side of the hotswap socket to the chosen GPIO (this picture shows it connect to 20, I used 21) - https://discord.com/channels/675924128108118016/713979311228715049/865068386848211004